# updatepanel and hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, updatepanel

In my database, I have some tables which have the same structure as "Folders" in Windows.
So a Folder may have inner folders and files.

To visualize the structure, I use the following asp.net controls

1. DataList, to list the data in MxN table
2. Inside, a **folder** will be displayed with HyperLink and Image

Now, is the design good ?
The behaviour of the architecture is as follows
1. If the **Folder A** is clicked, the page is posted back and will fetch the contents of **Folder A** in the same location in HTML file. To make it more good, can I use the "UpdatePanel" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are judging your design. On the coding side, it is easier to use a DataList, an UpdatePanel and postbacks. And yes, *you can* use an UpdatePanel here (generally speaking, you may use it whenever there is a postback in your ASP.NET pages). On the user experience and on the performance side, however, I would recommend using **ajax** here and load the content of each folder on demand using this technology.